Are projectors observable quantities in QM?
Given a certain quantum state $|\Psi\rangle$, then we can project any other quantum state $|\Phi\rangle$ on the first one by using the projector: $P_\Psi\equiv |\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|$ in such a way that the projected state would be given by: $|\Phi_\Psi\rangle=P_\Psi|\Phi\rangle$. It is evident that this projector operator is self-adjoint, since $(|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|)^\dagger=|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|$. Therefore, since we can associate a self-adjoint matrix representation to every projector, does this mean we can actually measure them as observables? If so, what physical quantity do they represent?
